iMA function parameters errors in MQL5 EA
I'm developing an EA in MQL5 and encountering 'iMA' - wrong parameters count errors. Here's the snippet causing issues:
FastMaCurrent = iMA(_Symbol, _Period, MaPeriodFast, 0, MaMethod, AppliedPrice, 0);Additionally,
I'm getting 'MagicNumber' - undeclared identifier errors.
Could anyone advise on resolving these?
